# how to declare and use the event handler for dynamically created array of textboxes in wp7 using C#?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm new to windows phone 7. I had created a array of textboxes dynamically. And I don't know where and how to declare and use the event handler for the textboxes. My code is shown below:

```
 public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public TextBox[] textbox;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string[] str = new string[2];
        str[0] = "force";
        str[1] = "force components";
         textbox = new TextBox[2];

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            textbox[i] = new TextBox { Text = str[i] };
    textbox[i].Tap += new System.EventHandler(this.textbox[i]_Tap);
            listBox1.Items.Add (textbox[i]);
        }
    }
private void textbox[0]_Tap(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {

     }
private void textbox[1]_Tap(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {

     }
 }
```

The above code shows error, while declaring and using the event handler method. please help me with a understandable piece of code, to clear my errors. Thank You for All.

Comment: What kind of error do you have?

Comment: the errors are:1) bad array declarator, and 2) array size cannot be specified in variable declaration and three more errors like expected ; and expected )

Comment: Seems like you're new not just to Windows Phone 7 but to C# and .Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot name a Method "private void textbox[1]_Tap" the [] is the thing which is not allowed. So even if you would name it: "private void textbox1_Tap", you wouldnt be able to call the function when you put an 'i' into it.

Thats because the Name of the Function is Reference and the Compiler later will not remember the Names of variables, functions, etc..